# R dplyr::ntile vs ggplot2::cut_number

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I need to divide a vector in quantiles, ie. bins with the same number of observations. I am currently looking at this two functions `dplyr::ntile` and `ggplot2::cut_number`. It looks like they do roughly the same thing. The only difference is that `ntile` gives back the quantile to which the observation belongs, ie. 1, 2, 3, ..., whereas `cut_number` returns the limits of the interval, ie. (0, 0.5], (0.5, 1], ... .
I did some experiments and it looks like I roughly get the same answers:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(vec = runif(1000))

df %>% mutate(vec_cut = cut_number(vec, 10)) %>% count(vec_cut)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    vec_cut               n
#>    <fct>             <int>
#>  1 [7.29e-05,0.0905]   100
#>  2 (0.0905,0.211]      100
#>  3 (0.211,0.325]       100
#>  4 (0.325,0.423]       100
#>  5 (0.423,0.5]         100
#>  6 (0.5,0.602]         100
#>  7 (0.602,0.699]       100
#>  8 (0.699,0.806]       100
#>  9 (0.806,0.91]        100
#> 10 (0.91,0.997]        100

df %>% mutate(vec_tile = ntile(vec, 10)) %>% 
  group_by(vec_tile) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(),
            min = min(vec), 
            max = max(vec))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    vec_tile count       min    max
#>       <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1        1   100 0.0000729 0.0905
#>  2        2   100 0.0905    0.210 
#>  3        3   100 0.211     0.324 
#>  4        4   100 0.325     0.422 
#>  5        5   100 0.423     0.499 
#>  6        6   100 0.501     0.602 
#>  7        7   100 0.602     0.699 
#>  8        8   100 0.702     0.806 
#>  9        9   100 0.806     0.910 
#> 10       10   100 0.911     0.997
```

The problem is that sometimes `cut_numbers` fails where `ntile` does not.

```r
vec <- c(rep(0,100), seq(1:100))

table(cut_number(vec, 10))
#> Error: Insufficient data values to produce 10 bins.
#> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

table(ntile(vec,10))
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#> 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

I could use `ntile`, however it is nice to have the interval limits and not just the index of the quantiles. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: cut_number is failing because the breaks are identical. One possible but slight hacky solution would be to add a very small amount of noise eg `vec <- rnorm(length(vec), vec, max(vec)/10e6)`

Comment: when you say breaks are identical, you mean I have identical observations?

Comment: In vec, you have 100 zeros